# Weird pyspark behavior when filtering on booleans

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

We have some existing code that used to work in Spark 3.1, and now is not working in Spark 3.3. It is really trivial code, so its blowing my mind why the filter isn't working:

```
widgets_df = widgets_df.filter(F.col("_id").isin(*widget_ids))
```

For some reason, even if there are rows where F.col("_id") is in widget_ids, we end up with an empty widgets_df.

So, we decided to refactor this some to debug whats going on

```
widgets_df = widgets_df.withColumn("IdMatch", F.col("_id").isin(widget_ids))

# print outs for debugging
widgets_df.printSchema()
widgets_df.show(vertical=True)
# We can clearly see the IdMatch column with value true on one row.
# IdMatch is of type Boolean

widgets_df = widgets_df.filter(F.col("IdMatch") == True) // But this will drop all rows
```

Again we have an empty widgets_df.

We are likely missing something relatively trivial here. What are we missing?

Comment: What if you filter like .filter(f.col("IdMatch")), as it's already a Boolean column?

Comment: Good point, but same difference. I am beyond lost.

Comment: Then I believe the code you show doesn't match the code you're running.